# Error: ‘is_same’ is not a member of ‘std’ when build c++ project in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, c++, g++

I have a small project and i get an error **‘is_same’ is not a member of ‘std’** when building.
this is some code:

```
template <class T>
T* UcmExportFactory::Unwrap (T* ptr)
{
    Utils::IUcmWrapper* wrapper = dynamic_cast<Utils::IUcmWrapper*> (ptr);

    // If the requested Ucm inteface is derived from an another (such as IUcmV from IUcmUnionValue), specify that whether we want the base class pointer or not.
    bool interfaceForAbstractBase = (std::is_same<IUcmUnionValue, T>::value || std::is_same<IUcmDiagCodedType, T>::value);
    return (wrapper) ? boost::any_cast<T*> ( wrapper->GetWrappedObject (interfaceForAbstractBase) ) : ptr;
}
```

Anyone can help me. I included header `#include <type_traits>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_same` is a C++11 feature. Ubuntu 12.04 has GCC 4.6.3, which has only incomplete [C++0x (not yet C++11)](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) support. You can try by specifying the standard:

```
g++ --std=c++0x ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder to anyone landing on this page, as the OP has stated he did this:

You'll also get this error if you do not include the `type_traits` header, so don't forget that:

```
#include <type_traits>
```